# Jclouds can't create instance

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, jclouds

I'm experiencing strange behavior during instance creation on Google Compute Engine.
When I try to create and start `ubuntu-1410-utopic` instance all is working as expected but if I try to create instance `ubuntu-1404-trusty` I get exception:

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: command: POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myProjectName/zones/asia-east1-a/instances HTTP/1.1 failed with response: HTTP/1.1 400 BadRequest; content:

```
[{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource.name': '615aa438-ef50-4c19-850b-e483a294d944-955'.  Must be a match of regex '(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)'"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource.name': '615aa438-ef50-4c19-850b-e483a294d944-955'.  Must be a match of regex '(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)'"
 }
}]
```

Why does this happens, and what is `resource.name`?

**UPDATE**

I found the answer, see answers sections.

Comment: Are you using the jclouds ComputeService? This looks like a bug in jclouds. Can you share the relevant code snippet you use and file a bug in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS ?

Comment: Can you tell me how do you create your GCE instance? share your code snippet or the steps you're taking so we can try to reproduce and find the issue.

Comment: Yes, it would be useful to see how you are trying to create your instance. Is resource.name your instance name? Please, take into account that resource names must start with a lowercase letter instead of a number as the error message says. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was dead simple. You can't create new instance on GCE if it's name starts with a digit. Use letters instead.

I had some random UUID as a name (`615aa438-ef50-4c19-850b-e483a294d944` in example above) and `jclouds` added some suffix (`-955` here).